# CSS - Nice way to do 'stepped' text?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a nice way of achieving the following, without any additional mark-up? It would be fine to use JavaScript though.

[image: Stepped text]

Any idea?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

My mark-up will be something like:

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <p>Text text text Text text text Text text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind altering the markup through Javascript?

Comment: what does your current markup looks like?

Comment: So you are saying you have markup like this `<div>Text text text Text text text Text text text</div>` and want to make it multi level? If not, please provide the sample markup you want to style.

Comment: Is HTML excluded? `<br>` followed by 2*i non-breaking spaces (U+00A0, `&nbsp;`) can do it, despite being rather low tech.

Comment: I guess he has something like `<div>Text text text</div>` and wants to repeat it like that

Comment: @Henning Makholm But that solution can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've updated my question with sample markup. I cannot use a combination of <br />'s and &nbsp;'s due to the text needing to be dynamic.

Comment: @feeela, which solution can be done with pure CSS?

Comment: @Probocop, so if I understand you correctly, you want automatic line breaking _and_ a stepping left margin? Should the right margin step too, or is it a coincidence that there just happens not to be room for the second `Text` to move up on the first line?

Comment: @Henning Makholm, I am just after a stepping left margin really, and for the text to just wrap automatically according to the width of the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given element of text, use a text range to find the end of the first line, then wrap the remaining text in a child div.  Repeat recursively, using the child div for the next iteration.

This works cross-browser: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/CmguZ/4/

It's easiest in IE thanks to `textRange.moveToPoint(x, y)`:

```
function indent(div) {
    var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
    rng.moveToElementText(div);
    var x = rng.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    rng.collapse();
    var rect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y = rect.bottom;
    rng.moveToPoint(x - 1, y - 1);
    rng.moveEnd("textedit");
    var html = "<div class=\"indent\">" + rng.text + "</div>";
    rng.pasteHTML(html);
    div = $(".indent", div)[0];
    rng.moveToElementText(div);
    var pos = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (pos.bottom > rect.bottom) {
        indent(div);
    }
}
```

With other browsers, you have to iterate the text to find where the line wraps:

```
function indent(div) {
    var rng = document.createRange();
    rng.selectNodeContents(div);
    var len = rng.toString().length;
    var start = rng.toString().search(/.\s/);
    if (start < 0) return;
    var txt = div.childNodes[0];
    rng.setEnd(txt, start);
    var startRect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect;
    for (var i = start + 1; i < len; i++) {
        rng.setEnd(txt, i);
        rect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.bottom > startRect.bottom) {
            rng.setStart(txt, i-1);
            rng.setEnd(txt, len);
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "indent";
            rng.surroundContents(div);
            indent(div);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thanks alot :)

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error when using the code: Parameter is not an object" Line 11 'rng.selectNodeContents(div);' - any idea?

Comment: The code snippets I pasted here are out of context.  They are meant to be part of a recursive function `indent()` which receives an element reference as a parameter.  See my JSFiddle for the complete context.  I'll also update my answer.

Comment: This will choke on content that has inline markup on it, such as `<strong>Foo</strong>`.

Comment: @sntran - Yep, that use case would require a more robust algorithm than mine.  I played with it long enough to see that it's possible, but not long enough to get a real working solution.  http://jsfiddle.net/CmguZ/139/

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you would do something like this:

```
var text = $('p').hide().html().split(' T');
text[1] = 'T' + text[1];
text[2] = 'T' + text[2];

$(text).each(function(index)
{
    var elem = $('<span>' + this + '</span>');
    elem.css({ position: relative; left: (index * 10) + 'px' });
    $('p').after(elem);
});
```

That should insert each span (which contains 'Text text text') after the paragraph element, with the second and third element offset by 10 and 20 px respectively (alter the math to suit your needs). It's kinda dirty, but whatever.

You would be much, **MUCH** better served by simply changing your markup and styling appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the content of my <div> could be anything, so I couldn't split it on a capitol T.