# Any way to have text in div fill a triangle shape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shapes

I'm trying to have a block of text in a div fill a downward triangle shape.  Is there any way to achieve this with either CSS or Javascript?

This is for a site in which users can dynamically insert text.  I'm trying to avoid the alternative method, which is to have them insert text line by line with a limit on each line.

Comment: Check out [this page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250285/css-nice-way-to-do-stepped-text/7250849#7250849).

I know of no CSS way, but you can do it with JavaScript.  The idea is to find where each line of text breaks and wrap the remaining text in a new child div.  You have to use text ranges to accomplish it.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/CmguZ/7/

Comment: Thanks Gilly!  Didn't see this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any simple way to do what you are asking for. The best thing I can think of would be to use something like the [CSS text wrapper](http://www.csstextwrap.com/), which can fit your text to any shape. I haven't used it myself so I don't know what problems you will run into.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each line of your text with a `<span>` and use  margins to recieve the wanted affect and if you want the shape to have a color use photoshop to create a triangle with the desired color and put it on the background.

Answer (score 0):

you can try playing with CSS border slopes, but I don't think it fits your needs entirely, because it's a bit complicated and you have to wrap the text manually. there are some good examples of this method [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes), but it is for simple shapes basically, not for text containers.